# Not going to sleep after SIGINT in C

Tags: c

I have the following code. How to bring the control back to cleanupCode() when I received SIGINT while sleeping? I don't want to use goto or jump. Calling cleanupCode inside handler is not an option.

```
sigHandler(int sig __atribute__((unused)) {

    loopFlag = 0; 
}

void cleanupCode() 
{  printf("Graceful exit \n");

} 
int main ()  {    
     while(loopFlag)
       sleep(600);
     cleanupCode(); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct sigaction SigAction;
static volatile sig_atomic_t loopFlag = 1;

static void sigHandler(int signum __attribute__((unused)))
{
    loopFlag = 0; 
}

static void cleanupCode(void) 
{
    printf("Graceful exit\n");
} 

static void setSignals(void)
{
    SigAction action;
    sigfillset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_handler = sigHandler;
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, 0);
}

int main(void)
{    
    setSignals();
    while (loopFlag)
        sleep(600);
    cleanupCode(); 
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the signal handler somewhere.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile int loopFlag = 1;

void sigHandler(int sig)
{
    loopFlag = 0;
}

void cleanupCode()
{
     printf("Graceful exit \n");
}

int main ()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);

     while(loopFlag)
       sleep(600);

     cleanupCode();
}
```

Comment: Note that `loopFlag` should be declared as `volatile sigatomic_t` to ensure well-defined behavior (the `sigatomic_t` is less important, but without `volatile`, the compiler might optimize the `while` loop into an infinite loop).

Comment: I got that sir. How do I get the control to cleanupCode() after handling signal? Thanks,

Comment: When the interrupt occurs, the signal handler (`sigHandler()`) is called and `loopFlag` is set to 0.  Since the handler returns, the code returns to the `sleep()`, but that returns when it is interrupted (rather than resuming its operation), so the while loop tests `loopFlag` and finds it is unset, and terminates the loop, executing the cleanup code.

Comment: Added volatile keyword.  @Kitcha - see Jonathan's explanation above.